# Segmentation fault when appending char to string in string array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

So I want to get all the lines from a file and turn them into a char* array. Problem is that whenever I try to append the character onto the end of the element it gives a segmentation fault.

```
char** loadOutputs(char *fileName, int *lineCount)
{
  FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
  if (file) {
    char c;
    int lines = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
      if (c = '\n')
        lines++;
    rewind(file);
    char **output = malloc(lines * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
      output[i] = "";

    int index = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
      if (c == '\n')
        index++;
      else
        strcat(output[i], &c);

    return output;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

I always get a segmentation fault at `strcat(output[i], &c);`. I'd rather not create a fixed array size for the output because this could get fairly large and I don't want to use too much memory.

Comment: `output[i]` points to a string literal, which you are not allowed to change. `&c` is not a terminated string. Both facts can lead to a segfault.

Comment: You have several problems here. One is that all the `output[i]` pointers point to the fixed string `""` which you cannot modify. You have to `malloc` space for each line separately. And also, `strcat` doesn't work for single characters. It needs a nul terminated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
   output[i] = "";
```

Is setting the pointer to an empty read only string.

You need to allocate some memory for the string:

I.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
  output[i] = malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1);
}
```

Where `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` is some defined constant - perhaps `#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 100`.

You will need to check that when reading the lines you do not exceed this length.

The following code will do this. This will resolve the other problem in that the address of `c` will not point to a null terminated string.

```
int index = 0;
int position = 0;
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
  if (c == '\n') {
    output[index][position] = 0; // Null terminate the line
    position = 0; // Restart next line
    index++;
  } else {
    if (position < MAX_LINE_LENGTH) { // Check if we have space!
       output[index][position] = c; // Add character and move forward
       position++;
    }
  }
}
output[index][position] = 0; // Add the null to the final line
```

Also you need to declare `c` as and int - i.e. change `char c` to `int c`. This is because EOF is outside the range for a `char`